# How to Enable verbose prints in ALSA kernel subsystem

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, alsa

I am pretty new to ALSA and kernel development. I am trying to add my own machine driver to register custom sound card. I want to see all the verbose prints form ALSA subsystem to dmesg ( or any other way). I enabled

> CONFIG_SND_VERBOSE_PRINTK=y

and

> CONFIG_SND_DEBUG=y

in kernel configuration , but not able to see verbose logs. Seems like I am missing some steps to get it working.

Any help ?

Note : My printk log level is already 7 (echo "8 4  1 7" > /proc/sys/kernel/printk)

Comment: https://docs.kernel.org/sound/designs/tracepoints.html

Comment: Went through the kernel document already. Could not resolve the problem. I am checking how i can enable all existing logs in alsa subsystem

Comment: If some trace events or points are missing, update the code (send upstream) and use them. `printk()` debug approach prone to timing and other issues. Not recommended to use.

Comment: https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/dynamic-debug-howto.html You may need to control dynamic debug to output messages from `pr_debug()` or `dev_dbg()` or similar depending on how `CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG` and `CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG_CORE` are configured.